Access Joomla login from another domain via CNAME
I have a client (seconddomain.com) who wants to setup a subdomain on their domain (learn.seconddomain.com) and point it to a login page on another of our client sites (firstdomain.com/seconddomain)
They have setup a CNAME on their domain (learn.seconddomain.com) which loads the page firstdomain.com/seconddomain correctly.
Howevever, when trying to login using learn.seconddomain.com the page is just refreshing and not allowing anyone to login, yet if we go to firstdomain.com/seconddomain the page allows logins correctly.
This is running Joomla 3.10.12 (we need to update I know), I suspect this is down to security. But what is the best way to do this?
I have updated the .htacess and added:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^learn\.seconddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://firstdomain.com/seconddomain/$1 [L,R=301]

But it's not allowing users to login when accessing via learn.seconddomain.com.

"They have setup a CNAME on their domain (learn.seconddomain.com) which loads the page firstdomain.com/seconddomain correctly" - The CNAME alone does not do that. The CNAME can only point to a domain, eg. firstdomain.com. Are you seeing a 301 redirect to https://firstdomain.com/seconddomain/...? Or are you still seeing learn.seconddomain.com in the browser's address bar? "I have updated the .htacess and added:" - to which .htaccess file? And where in that .htaccess file?

Do you have any values entered into the Cookie Settings section under Global Configuration's Site tab?
